# Why the value into the column is always 1?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table *employees* with 2 columns

1. **Tiny** with the content of the textarea
2. **Photo** with the pics name.

Now when I write in the textarea, into the column **Tiny** the value is always **1** but in the second there is the name of the pics. What is wrong in this code?

Details of the column `Tiny`:

```
Tiny Varchar(30) NULL
```

Markup and code:

```
<div id="main">
    <h2>Posta un nuovo film o una serie</h2>
    <p>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="amministrazione.php" method="POST"> 
    <textarea id="name" name="tiny" rows="15" cols="80"></textarea><br> 
    <label for="photo">Copertina DVD | Serie  </label>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="file" name="photo"><br><br> 
 <input type="submit" value="Crea"> 
 <?php 

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $target = "../image/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

 //This gets all the other information from the form 

 $tiny = (isset($_POST['tiny'])); 

 $pic= ($_FILES['photo']['name']); 



 mysql_query("INSERT INTO employees VALUES ('$tiny', '$pic')") ; 

 //Writes the photo to the server 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "The file ". basename(isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
 } 
 else { 

 //Gives and error if its not 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 

 ?> 
 </form>

    </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$tiny = (isset($_POST['tiny']));
```

Should be

```
$tiny = $_POST['tiny'];
```

Besides:

1. You are using deprecated mysql_* functions
2. You have possible SQL Injection in you code (put ' into textarea ;) )

Comment: Option hard : put @ berfore $_POST

Comment: Option clean: isset($_POST['tiny']) ? $_POST['tiny'] : '';

Comment: Don't work, now recieve the notice "Undefined varible: tiny" the row is that:  mysql_query("INSERT INTO employees VALUES ('$tiny', '$pic')") ;

Comment: Have you $tiny = @$_POST['tiny']; or $tiny = isset($_POST['tiny']) ? $_POST['tiny'] : '';

Comment: Another problem, now Undefined index photo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$tiny = (isset($_POST['tiny']));
```

should be

```
$tiny = (isset($_POST['tiny']))  ? $_POST['tiny'] : null
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the isset() function. This will always return True or False, 1 or 0.

```
$tiny = (isset($_POST['tiny']));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Using this will set the variable correctly.

```
$tiny = $_POST['tiny'];
```

Try rewriting your query like this to spruce up security and stability.. Be specific about where the data need to go by specifying the columns then the data. Also secure your table references in backticks.

```
INSERT INTO `employees` (`columnname1`, `columnname2`) VALUES ('$tiny', '$pic')
```

Finally, consider using the current version of mySQLi as the one you are using is obsolete.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Hope you find this helpful

Comment: i made wrong the columns in the database and i it "work". So now when i write much text in the textarea don't work but if i write a little text it work :\